# Webcenter Sites Satellite server can't read query strings?

Tags: webcenter-sites

In our installation, we have a satellite server in front of sites (11.1.1.8.0 with patch 4 applied). When we pass query string to satellite, it doesn't read it. The issue occurs whether we use Vanity or long URLs.
For example, assume we entered the following url in the browser:
http: //host:port/context?param=value

Satellite acts as if there's no query string entered. However the same scenario works fine if we bypassed Satellite and communicated directly with Sites.
Is there any required configuration on satellite server side to enable it to understand query strings in the URL ?

Comment: How you're getting the query string params? ics.GetVar() or request.getParameter()?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is not with SS but with apache httpd? Your example gives

```
http://host:port/context?param=value
```

whilst the typical vanilla SS url looks like

```
http://host:port/context/Satellite?param=value
```

so maybe you are testing via the webserver address and are using url rewriting? That can alter the query string.